# Enum Composition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I've had a hard time finding examples of OO Enum composition in Python. So I wanted to ask if the following example is correct or more pythonic ways are advisable?

I prefer class syntax in declaring Enum but it seems for composition Functional API is advisable. Any way to do this using class syntax?

```
from enum import Enum


class Vertical(Enum):

    Tall = 1
    Short = 2


class Horizontal(Enum):

    Slim = 1
    Spacious = 2


composition = list(Vertical.__members__)
composition.extend(Horizontal.__members__)

Body = Enum('Body', composition)
```

Comment: Are you aware that with the above code: `Vertical.Tall is Body.Tall` is `False`?

Comment: Yes I am aware sir. But composition is cognitively so intuitive I will rather figure out a workaround for the truth test than give up on object composition. More so, when modeling natural discreet data focused on domain analyses, because a bottom-up approach would always start with Enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot derive enums, they are "sealed":

```
class Body(Vertical): pass
```

leads to `TypeError: Cannot extend enumerations`.

---

If you want your composed enums to compare equal you can use `IntEnum`s:

```
from enum import IntEnum 

class Vertical(IntEnum ):
    Tall = 1
    Short = 2 

class Horizontal(IntEnum):  # distinct int's
    Slim = 3
    Spacious = 4 

composition = list(Vertical.__members__)
composition.extend(Horizontal.__members__)

Body = IntEnum('Body', composition)
```

Usage:

```
print(Body.Tall == Vertical.Tall)  # True
print(Body.Tall == 1)              # Also True
```

Essentially it boils down to : your enums are now also int's. You need to take care to not give the same integer to different concepts though:

```
class Sizes(IntEnum):
    Tiny = 1

print(Sizes.Tiny == Vertical.Tall)  # True - but not really?
```

Comment: **Ontologically**, this is correct. `Man.Tall is Building.Tall` is `False`. But `Man.Tall == Building.Tall` is `True`. (They are not the same, but both are Tall.) And your solution provides both `==` syntax comparison, and `is` difference.